# Replace a sequence of characters with a sequence of different characters of same length using regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have a string which starts with spaces. I want to replace the leading spaces with equal number of dashes `-`. I don't want to replace any other spaces which may occur elsewhere in the string.

If I use `/^\s*/-/`, it only replaces with a single dash. If I use `/^\s/-/`, it only replaces the first space with a dash. If I remove the anchor `/\s/-/`, it replaces every occurences of space in the string which is not acceptable.

My string looks like this in general:

```
<n-leading-spaces><a-non-space-character><remaining-characters>
```

Example (pipes added to show the boundary):

```
|   ajfn ssfdjn ng jnv sjfj%nv sjfj n     s ;sn     |
```

After substitution (pipes added to show the boundary):

```
|---ajfn ssfdjn ng jnv sjfj%nv sjfj n     s ;sn     |
```

**NOTE**: I cannot use any code snippet. I just want to know whether this can be done using just regex patterns. (Forgive my formatting as I'm new to markdown. I welcome formatting corrections)

Comment: Can you provide some sample strings?

Comment: Take this string for example: `      a b c d e   ` (there are 8 leading spaces).  I would like it to be changed to `--------a b c d e   `.

Comment: Add a few examples to your OP.

Comment: Is there an upper limit on the number of leading spaces?

Comment: @CertainPerformance theoretically, no!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following solution to replace a sequence of characters with a sequence of different characters of same length using regular expressions:

```
my $string = '    ajfn ssfdjn ng jnv sjfj%nv sjfj n     s ;sn     ';
$string =~ s/^(\s+)/"-" x length($1)/eg;
print $string;

Returns '----ajfn ssfdjn ng jnv sjfj%nv sjfj n     s ;sn     '
```

Comment: Thanks. But coding is not an issue here. Suppose you want a sed command like 's///' What will be the regex? Deeper question - whether it is possible with just a sed command string? It is not a question of how to do it. I have already decided. i only want to know whether it can be done by just regex substitution string. If yes, then how?

Comment: s/^(\s+)/"-" x length($1)/eg    =     s///

Comment: the only way is to tell it to execute code in the second part (ie. the e switch)